# Server slow in some domains

Tags: iis, logging

I have a application developed using .NET and running on a IIS server. The application is a blog network, that has many different domains. When we activate one domain that uses a differente domain alias the server stay really slow. We think that the application can not handle this alias. How can I analyze this on IIS? Someone has this problem too? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is caused by disk space. You can try to check your task manager. How is the traffic?